# Help solving a problem on plotting a graph

Tags: coordinate-systems

The question is to plot two points lying on y-axis which are equal distance from the origin.What is the exact meaning of the question and how do I solve it?Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $y$-axis is the vertical line through the origin. 
 So you'll need one point directly above the origin and one directly below. 
But they must the the same distance above/below the origin.
 So the $x-y$ coordinates of your two points will be $(0,y)$ and $(0,-y)$, and you can pick whatever value for $y$ you like.